# Cocos2d-x v3 from github : Don't have glfw3.h

Tags: ios, macos, cocos2d-x

After I followed the steps on [how to run cpp test on Mac OsX](https://web.archive.org/web/20171011104621/https://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Mac_OS_X), there is an error when I run it in Xcode. It says that:

```
 #include "glfw3.h <--- file not found
```

When I checked the folder, where I downloaded it from github, it seems that there is no `glfw` folder or even a file that was needed here.

So probably the files are missing. Please guide me on what could be done here to resolve this issue. Need guidance. I am using OS X version 10.9 and have Xcode 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the doc?

You need to run `python download-deps.py`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am a newbie, you mean I need more steps to follow from doc? in the docs folder it contains picture .md file doxygen.config  2 .h file and another .md file?

Comment: The readme on github states that you need to run the python script to download the dependencies.

Comment: maybe im wrong, isnt ok if i download it right a way by clicking the Download zip button?

Comment: Doing so you only get the cocos2d code, none of the dependency. After getting the zip from github, you need to run `python download-deps.py` to get the dependencies like GLFW.